# Rstudio: Cmd + C/V not working in editor

Tags: r, rstudio

I have used `pipe` to copy and paste data between Rstudio (v0.99.467) and Excel on my Mac OSX 10.9.5.

```
pipe("pbcopy", "w")
pipe("pbpaste")
```

For some time, I tried to use `pipe("pbcopy", "r")`, but Rstudio is not responding (because my code is wrong). After a while, I found Cmd + C/V is not working in the editor any more (but it still works in the R console). I re-install R-studio, removed `.rstudio-desktop`, the problem still exists. Does anyone know what is going on? Can I remove the .bash file that stores the Rstudio shortcut preferences (assuming re-install won't delete it)? BTW, where is the shortcut .bash file in Rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

On OSX Mojave using R 3.5.1, you can use the following block to capture the clipboard:

```
clipboard <- system("pbpaste", intern = T)
```

I can also confirm that the following block is working:

```
clipboard <- scan(pipe("pbpaste", "r"), what = character())
```

However, connections are sometimes tricky to work with. For example:

```
clipboard <- readLines(pipe("pbpaste", "r"))
```

Returns an empty character vector, likely because there's no newline terminator in the clipboard!