# important hotkeys don't work anymore after RStudio update to 0.99.878

Tags: r, cursor, rstudio, hotkeys, gtd

I recently updated RStudio for Windows via [download link](https://download1.rstudio.org/RStudio-0.99.878.exe) mainly due to interest in the new features of the most recent version 0.99.878. Unfortunaly after the installation some important hotkeys behave different in the source editor, while they still work in the Console. I.e.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> starts an "isearch"
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> jumps to the end of the document

When I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+(<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd>) the hotkeys work as they should. The hotkeys can be customized, however when I open the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog it shows me the settings for the hotkeys.  Also the cursor has turned to a shiny green rectangle (`insert` isn't activated).

The problems remains after switching the project. Also reinstalling Rstudio 0.99.878 didn't work out. I've seen a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017681/rstudio-cmd-c-v-not-working-in-editor), but think mine is different as it is installation related. I might have accidentally activated a special editor setting but couldn't find any.

Comment: Did you try to [customize your keyboard shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts)?

Comment: These kinds of questions have a better chance of being answered on the RStudio support website. This is not a programming question.  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a report of difference in behaviour after updating to the version that was released a few days ago. It should be reported on the support website of RStudio, which I linked to in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have (accidentally?) activated Emacs keybindings. If you go to `Tools -> Global Options...`, you can reset the preference here:

[image]